# Bad: php session

Tags: php, syntax

I need help figuring out what the problem is, the error text (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file) link to the last line of the file.

```php
<?php
//require_once 'имя_файла.php'; подключение файла к другому
$animals = require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/data/animals-data.php'; // благодаря return в файле массив оказывается в переменной 
$user_data = require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/data/user-data.php';

// $_SERVER суперглобальный массив который хранит информацию о сервере 
// DOCUMENT_ROOT - корневая директория сервера 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Зверинец</title>
</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <h2>Все животные</h2>

        <?php foreach ($animals as $animal) : ?>
            <div>
                <h3><?= $animal['name'] ?></h3>
                <div>
                    <img height="300" src="/img/<?= $animal['img'] ?>">
                </div>
                <? if ($user_data['role'] === 'admin') : ?>
                    <button>Перейти к редактированию</button>
                <? endif; ?>
            </div>
        <? endforeach; ?>
    </section>
</body>

</html>

<?php ?>
```

I tried adding  at the end but it does not help.

Comment: what row do you have that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you just need to replace `<?` with `<?php`

Have a look at the standard suggestion in php-fig at this URL: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/

Answer (score 0):

`<? endforeach; ?>` replace to `<?php endforeach; ?>`